# How to change start position on mobile for Owl Carousel

Tags: owl-carousel

I have 3 item on my Owl Carousel But I dont want to show all of them on mobile device or I want to start the Carousel from 2nd position. To do this I use

```
startPosition:
```

Still not working . is there any good solution for this.

```
$('.reviews').owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        margin:10,
        autoplay:false,
        lazyLoad:true,
        startPosition: 1,
        autoplayTimeout:3000,
        autoplayHoverPause:true,
        responsiveClass:true,
        navText : ["<i class='fa fa-angle-left ca-left-arrow'></i>","<i class='fa fa-angle-right ca-right-arrow'></i>"],
        responsive:{
            0:{
                items:1,
                nav:true,
            },
            480:{
                items:1,
                nav:true,
                autoplay:true,
            },

            600:{
                items:2,
                nav:true,
                autoplay:true,
            },
            1000:{
                items:3,
                nav:false,
                loop:true,
                autoplay:false,
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var owl = $('.reviews').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    autoplay:false,
    lazyLoad:true,
    startPosition: 1,
    autoplayTimeout:3000,
    autoplayHoverPause:true,
    responsiveClass:true,
    navText : ["<i class='fa fa-angle-left ca-left-arrow'></i>","<i class='fa fa-angle-right ca-right-arrow'></i>"],
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1,
            nav:true,
        },
        480:{
            items:1,
            nav:true,
            autoplay:true,
        },

        600:{
            items:2,
            nav:true,
            autoplay:true,
        },
        1000:{
            items:3,
            nav:false,
            loop:true,
            autoplay:false,
        }
    }
})
owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', index);
```

Index being the number you want to start on.